# All white in Eevee render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

When I try to render image or animation it firts turns normal (1st image) but then it become all white (image 2)[image]

Also there is link for [.blend file](https://mega.nz/file/u7pmjCRa#2xuJ2BGeqwqlM-R1lUof-MMgIRDNQjangs1fIuaJHuI)
Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) Number 2 on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render layer is not connected to any nodes in the compositor!

[image]

Disconnected nodes have no effect on the render image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice that because it was first time I used Compositing tab )